# Как правильно подключить файл *.a в файл *.pro

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator

Хочу подключить библиотеку для парсинга *.xls. Решил воспользоваться вот [этой](http://libxls.sourceforge.net/) библиотекой. Из мунуала:

> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
> #include <libxls/xls.h>
> ```
>
> You also need to link with libxlsreader.a.

В данный момент библиотека подключена таким образом:

```
LIBS += \
    c:/Users/blalba/blalba/blalba/Doverka/libxls/lib/libxlsreader.a
```

Код *.h:

```
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QDebug>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <libxls/include/libxls/xls.h>

namespace Ui {
class Doverka;
}

class Doverka : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Doverka(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Doverka();

private:
    Ui::Doverka *ui;
};
```

Код *.cpp:

```
Doverka::Doverka(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Doverka)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    xlsWorkBook* book = new xlsWorkBook;
    book = xls_open("examles/230517.xls", "iso-8859-15//TRANSLIT");
    qDebug() << book->sheets.count;
    delete book;
}
```

При выполнении дает следующую ошибку:

> Doverka\doverka.cpp:11: ошибка: undefined reference to
>   `xls_open(char*, char*)'

На форумах я нашел, что обычно эта ошибка выскакивает при неправильной линковке библиотеки. Но как правильно ее линкануть, не понятно. Может кто-то подсказать?

Comment: Это ошибка точно возникает про выполнении, а не при линковке? Приведи командную строку линкера. Не забыл ли ты сделать qmake после обновления файла *.pro ?

Comment: "Не забыл ли ты сделать qmake после обновления файла *.pro ?" - сделал, не помогло. "Это ошибка точно возникает про выполнении, а не при линковке?" - да, если закоментить строку 'book = xls_open("examles/230517.xls", "iso-8859-15//TRANSLIT");' проект собирается.

Comment: 'LIBS += \
    libxls/lib/libxlsreader.a' - ошибка линковки - >> :-1: ошибка: cannot find -lxls/lib/libxlsreader.a

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для подключение статической библиотеки `.a` нужно прописать в `.pro` файл следующее:

```
LIBS += -L[путь к библиотеке] -l[имя библиотеки]
```

Обратите внимание, что имя библиотеки `lib[nameOfLib].a` и нужно указать только оригинальную часть `-l[nameOfLib]`.

<sup>На основании [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1361282/3240681) с enSO.</sup>